# Snake game on a 9×9 grid

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

You are playing a snake game. The snake starts in the top-left corner of a grid. Each cell of the grid is either empty or a wall. Each turn you can press a key to move the snake in one of four directions: either horizontally or vertically. Once a key is pressed, the snake moves in the assigned direction until it either reaches a wall or the boundary of the grid. Can you construct a $9 \times 9$ grid with $4$ walls such that the snake is able to visit every empty cell of the grid?

Here is a simpler version of this puzzle: [Snake game on a 6×6 grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109481/snake-game-on-a-6%c3%976-grid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

> ```
>     0   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   1
>
>     3   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   2
>
>     4   .   .   .   .   .   .   5   X
>
>     X   20  .   .   .   .   .   .   19
>
>     13  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   14
>     &17                             &18
>     16  .   .   .   .   .   .   .   15
>
>     .   21  .   .   .   .   .   22  X
>
>     .   X   9   .   .   .   .   .   8
>                                     &10
>     12  .   .   .   .   .   .   6   7
>                                     &11
>
>     0,1,2,3,...: move number
>     X: wall
> ```

Comment: Yes that's the solution I had in mind. Well done! Are there any other solutions?